# About The last blog Article "How to calculate maximum amount of memory consumed by OrientDB"

Tags: orientdb

I read the last blog's article http://orientdb.com/memory-consumed-by-orientdb/.

In that article  Andrey Lomakin says "...the storage.diskCache.bufferSize configuration parameter, which shows the maximum amount of memory consumed by the disk cache in pages", but the documentation says storage.diskCache.bufferSize Size of disk buffer in megabytes..

So I'm just a little confused about that sentence. Is it for the 2.1.x also?

Answer (score 1):

I find [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Configuration.html#storage) section in the OrientDB official documentation about the 2.1.x version.

As you can see, it's written that the `storage.diskCache.bufferSize` is the size of disk buffer in megabytes.

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in blog, we will fix it soon.